# parsing a simple repeated text macro with Boost.spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit-qi

I'm learning how to use Boost.Spirit library for parsing strings. It seems to be a very nice tool but difficult as well. So, I want to parse a string with some words separated with `/` and put them in a vector of strings. Here is an example:`word1/word2/word3`. That's a simple task, I can do this with the following finction:

```
bool r = phrase_parse(first, last, (+~char_("/") % qi::lit("/")),space,v)
```

where `v` is `std::vector<std::string>`. But in general, I'd like to parse something like `w1/[w2/w3]2/w4` which is equivalent to `w1/w2/w3/w2/w3/w4`, that is `[w2/w3]2` means that `w2/w3` is repeated twice. Could anyone give me some ideas on that? I read the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) but still have some problems.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should first write down an ebnf syntax of the format you want to parse.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The title you chose for this question is a little vague. The entire purpose of Boost.Spirit is to parse strings. Do you think you could [edit] it so that it's something more specific to *your* issue, instead of being equally applicable to *every* Spirit question ever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fully working demo: **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a5d6bd0dfd0fd832103f5165dac13ead-f468fd186ebe6d5f25efae86bd4f0130)**

What this adds over a naive approach is that `raw` values are optionally ended at `]` if the state is `in_group`.

I elected pass the state using an *inherited attribute* (`bool`).

This implementation allows *nested* sub-groups as well, e.g.: `"[w1/[w2/w3]2/w4]3"`

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    const std::string input = "[w1/[w2/w3]2/w4]3";

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    It first(input.begin()), last(input.end());

    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

    rule<It, std::string(bool in_group)> raw;
    rule<It, std::vector<std::string>(bool in_group), space_type> 
        group, 
        delimited;

    _r1_type in_group; // friendly alias for the inherited attribute

    raw       = eps(in_group) >> +~char_("/]") 
              | +~char_("/");

    delimited = (group(in_group)|raw(in_group)) % '/';

    group     = ('[' >> delimited(in_group=true) >> ']' >> int_) 
        [ phx::while_(_2--) 
            [ phx::insert(_val, phx::end(_val), phx::begin(_1), phx::end(_1)) ]
        ];

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((raw)(delimited)(group));

    bool r = phrase_parse(first, last, 
            delimited(false),
            space,v);

    if (r)
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Prints:

```
w1
w2
w3
w2
w3
w4
w1
w2
w3
w2
w3
w4
w1
w2
w3
w2
w3
w4
```

(besides debug info)

Comment: Made this a bit more readable by aliasing `_r1` to `in_group`

Comment: Removed c++11 bits because they were irrelevant to the answer and didn't really simplify much

Answer (score 2):

This is my quick implementation ( c++11 ). You can find a lot of scenarios how to tackle various problems in [boost-spirit-qi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-spirit-qi) and I agree learning SPIRIT takes some effort :-)

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

struct SInsert
{
    struct result
    {
        typedef void type;
    };

    void operator()( std::vector<std::string>&out, 
                     std::vector<std::string>&in, int counter ) const
    {
        for( int i=0; i<counter; ++i )
            std::copy( in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out) );
    }
};

boost::phoenix::function<SInsert> inserter;

int main()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    for ( auto &str : std::vector< std::string >
        {   "w1/ w2 /w4 ",
            "[w2]1 /w4 ",
            "[w2/w3]2 /w4 ",
            "[]0",
            "[]0 / w4"
        }
    )
    {
        std::cout << "input:" << str << std::endl;
        std::string::const_iterator iter( str.begin() );
        std::string::const_iterator last( str.end() );
        std::vector< std::string > v;

        qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,
            qi::locals< std::vector<std::string>  >,
            ascii::space_type ,std::vector<std::string>()> mrule =
                ( qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +(qi::graph -"/"-"[") ] ][ ph::push_back( qi::_val,qi::_1 )] |
                    (
                        qi::lit("[")
                            >> -(
                                    qi::eps[ ph::clear( qi::_a ) ]
                                    >> qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +(qi::graph-"/"-"]") ] ][  ph::push_back( qi::_a ,qi::_1 ) ]
                                    % qi::lit("/")
                                )
                    )
                    >> qi::lit("]" )
                    >> qi::int_[ inserter( qi::_val,qi::_a,qi::_1 ) ]
                )
                % qi::lit("/");

        if( qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, mrule , ascii::space, v ) && iter==last )
            std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>( std::cout,"\n" ));
        else
           std::cerr << "parsing failed:" << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can further simplify the `mrule` so that the attributes are synthesized automatically rather than using semantic actions - even though you wont avoid them altogether:

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,
    qi::locals< std::vector<std::string>  >,
    ascii::space_type ,std::vector<std::string>()> mrule;
    mrule %=
        (
            qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +(qi::graph -"/"-"[") ] ] |                      
                qi::lit("[")
                    >> -(
                            qi::eps[ ph::clear( qi::_a ) ]
                            >> qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +(qi::graph-"/"-"]") ] ][ ph::push_back( qi::_a ,qi::_1 ) ]
                            % qi::lit("/")
                        )
            >> qi::lit("]" )
            >> qi::omit[ qi::int_[ inserter( qi::_val,qi::_a,qi::_1-1 ) ] ]
        )
        % qi::lit("/");
```

As `sehe` pointed to some ugly constructs, here is minor simplification:

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator,
    qi::locals< std::vector<std::string>  >,
    ascii::space_type ,std::vector<std::string>()> mrule;
mrule %= (
            qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +qi::alnum ] ] |
            qi::lit("[")
               >> -(
                   qi::eps[ ph::clear( qi::_a ) ] >>
                   qi::as_string[ qi::lexeme[ +qi::alnum ] ][ ph::push_back( qi::_a ,qi::_1 ) ]
                   % qi::lit("/")
                   )
                   >> qi::lit("]")
                   >> qi::omit[ qi::int_[ inserter( qi::_val,qi::_a,qi::_1-1 ) ] ]
            ) % qi::lit("/");
```

Comment: Hehe. I kinda chuckled at _'You can further simplify'_. +1 for effort though. I'm trying to decide which version I like better, yours or mine :)

Comment: @sehe I think my version is easier for beginners :-)

Comment: Sadly, I cannot agree. I have just inspected it more closely. The use of `qi::locals`, many semantic actions and 'spurious' parser hints (like `-'['`) make it hard. Also, the christmas tree code layout makes it harder.

Comment: Also, note that your version will simply fail to parse `"w1/[w2/[w3]3]2/w4"` without warning

Comment: why would I doubt what I see? Jokes aside, it still fails to parse :)

Comment: @sehe that's correct - the question was asking about `simple` repeat :-) Jokes aside - I like your `simple` way to repeat a group using phx::while and phx::insert - it's neat.

Comment: Thank you! I like it too. I should upvote that too. Oh wait :/ Cheers