# Setting attributes from semantic action(s) for expression passed into qi::phrase_parse

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

During parsing I have a few attributes that I need to set in semantic action only ( as they are derived from data being parsed and I want to avoid `global` variables  and dependency on `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` as well as my code should be generic so that I can reuse it for multiple types). If I use more than one variable passed into `qi::phrase_parse`  I get very long list of compilation errors. I need a help badly :-)

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    bool rc;
    std::string input("");

    //Test case 1 works fine
    {
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        int val1=33;
        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, qi::eps[ qi::_val=11 ] , 
                   ascii::space, val1 ) && iter==last;
        if( rc )
            std::cout << "val1=" << val1 << std::endl; 
    }
    //Test case 2 does not compile
    {
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        int val1=33;
        int val2=0;
        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, 
                qi::eps[ ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)=1,ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)=2 ],
                ascii::space, val1,val2 ) && iter==last;
        if( rc )
            std::cout << "val1=" << val1 << 
                         " val2=" << val2 << std::endl;         
    }
    //Test case 3 works fine
    {
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        int val1=33;
        int val2=0;
        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last,
                qi::attr(1)>>qi::attr(2),
                ascii::space, val1,val2 ) && iter==last;
        if( rc )
            std::cout << "val1=" << val1 <<
                         " val2=" << val2 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I took the "customized" my_phrase_parse from `cv_and_he` but it breaks compilation on the full test case that I want to get running:

```
template<typename T,typename R>
void testParser( R rule )
{
    for ( const auto input : std::vector< std::string >{ "5 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0", "1 1.0", "0" , "", "2 3 ab" } )
    {
        bool rc;
        T maxValue;
        T minValue;
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        std::vector< T > v;
        rc = my_phrase_parse( iter, last,
            qi::eps[
                     ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)=std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),
                     ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)=std::numeric_limits<T>::min()
                   ]
            >> -( qi::omit[ qi::int_] 
            >> *rule[ ph::if_(ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)>qi::_1)[ ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)=qi::_1 ],
                      ph::if_(ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)<qi::_1)[ ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)=qi::_1 ]
                    ] )
                ,ascii::space, minValue, maxValue,v ) && iter==last;
        std::cout << ( rc ? "ok :`" : "err:`" ) << input << "` -> ";
        if( rc )
        {
            std::cout << "min=" << minValue << " max=" << maxValue << "\t";
            std::copy( v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>( std::cout," " ));
        }
        else
            std::cout << *iter;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
...
    testParser<double>( qi::double_ );
```

Comment: [Before Boost 1.47.0 your first example wouldn't work](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2011/02/26/using-_val-in-top-level-semantic-actions/). In that version a fix was applied to the "normal" `parse` and `phrase_parse`, but apparently not to the "variadic" ones. If you create a rule like `qi::rule<decltype(iter),fusion::vector<int&, int&>(),ascii::space_type> parser=qi::eps[ ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)=1,ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)=2 ];` it will work.

Comment: @cv_and_he Hi, Thanks for your feedback. I'm using 1_52. if the single variable case did not work I would not have asked the question as it would have been obvious :-) because I can avoid the problem with `test case 3` generating the values using attr.

Comment: I know it works. If you read the link, you see that the only reason that it works is because it was changed for `parse` and `phrase_parse` with a single attribute only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Phoenix placeholders that Spirit uses](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/phoenix.html) allow you to manipulate important information from a rule's Context. When you use them directly in an expression in a call to `parse` or `phrase_parse` there is no rule, and thus no context. Before version Boost 1.47.0 that didn't work, and in order to make this behaviour consistent a fix was applied to the single argument versions of those functions, but apparently not to the variadic ones.

One way to sidestep this problem is creating a rule that has as attribute a `fusion::vector` of references to the types you use in your call to `phrase_parse`.

**Edit: removed "my_phrase_parse" since I'm not confident that it is correct**

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    bool rc;
    std::string input("");

    //Test case works fine
    {
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        int val1=33;
        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, qi::eps[ qi::_val=11 ] , 
                   ascii::space, val1 ) && iter==last;
        if( rc )
            std::cout << "val1=" << val1 << std::endl; 
    }
    //You can use a rule
    {
        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        int val1=33;
        int val2=0;

        qi::rule<decltype(iter),fusion::vector<int&, int&>(),ascii::space_type> parser=qi::eps[ ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val)=1,ph::at_c<1>(qi::_val)=2 ];

        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, 
                parser,
                ascii::space, val1,val2 ) && iter==last;
        if( rc )
            std::cout << "val1=" << val1 << 
                         " val2=" << val2 << std::endl;      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 2: Added another way to approach the problem you want to solve in your edit**

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_omit.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename T>
struct min_max_set
{
    min_max_set():min(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()),max(std::numeric_limits<T>::min()),set(){}
    T min;
    T max;
    std::vector<T> set;
};

namespace boost{ namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <typename T>
    struct is_container<min_max_set<T>>
        : boost::mpl::true_
    {};

    template <typename T>
    struct container_value<min_max_set<T>>
    {
        typedef T type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct push_back_container<min_max_set<T>,T>
    {
        static bool call(min_max_set<T>& cont, const T& val)
        {
            if(cont.min>val)
                cont.min=val;
            if(cont.max<val)
                cont.max=val;
            cont.set.push_back(val);
            return true;
        }
    };

}}}

template<typename T,typename R>
void testParser( R rule )
{
    for ( const auto input : std::vector< std::string >{ "5 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0", "1 1.0", "0" , "", "2 3 ab" } )
    {
        bool rc;

        auto iter( input.begin() );
        auto last( input.end() );
        min_max_set<T> accum;   

        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last,
                qi::omit[qi::int_] >> *rule
                ,ascii::space, accum ) && iter==last;
        std::cout << ( rc ? "ok :`" : "err:`" ) << input << "` -> ";
        if( rc )
        {
            std::cout << "min=" << accum.min << " max=" << accum.max << "\t";
            std::copy( accum.set.begin(), accum.set.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>( std::cout," " ));
        }
        else
            std::cout << *iter;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}


int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    testParser<double>(qi::double_);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the `detailed` response. It saved me from Sunday afternoon frustration :-)

Comment: Don't trust that `my_phrase_parse` is 100% correct, since I basically don't know what I'm doing. "It seems to work" is the only guarantee I can make.

Comment: Would you mind If I extend the question? I adopted your code but if I add a couple of rules to the eps expression that should synthesize attrs automatically .. it does not compile again :-( Or should I open a new question?

Comment: Edit it in, if it turns out that it is a different problem you can always create a new question.

Comment: I can't make it work, but I'm not sure that it is a problem with this solution. If you think it is just unaccept the answer and I'll remove it. I prefer avoiding that semantic action hell by making a struct behave as if it were a container. You can see an example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=c3927edbb2650aae24a56f553154b4e5-e7fd08290543cba3074dbc20a85c5c10). You just need to initialize min and max in the constructor and then specialize `is_container`, `container_value` and `push_back_container`.

Answer (score 1):

This is `workaround` for my initial problem:

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template<typename T,typename R>
void testParser( R rule )
{
    for ( const auto &input : std::vector< std::string >{ "5 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0" } )
    {
        bool rc=false;
        T maxValue, minValue;
        auto iter( input.begin() ), last( input.end() );
        std::vector< T > data;

        qi::rule< decltype(iter),std::vector<T>( T&, T& ),qi::space_type > mrule;

        mrule %=
            qi::eps[ qi::_r1=std::numeric_limits<T>::max(),
                     qi::_r2=std::numeric_limits<T>::min() ] >>
             -( qi::omit[ qi::int_[ ph::reserve( qi::_val,qi::_1 ) ] ]
                >> *rule[ ph::if_(qi::_r1>qi::_1)[ qi::_r1=qi::_1 ],
                          ph::if_(qi::_r2<qi::_1)[ qi::_r2=qi::_1 ]
                        ] );

        rc = qi::phrase_parse( iter, last, mrule( ph::ref(minValue), ph::ref(maxValue) ), qi::space, data ) && iter==last;

    std::cout << ( rc ? "ok :`" : "err:`" ) << input << "` -> ";
    if( rc )
    {
        std::cout << "min=" << minValue << " max=" << maxValue << "\t";
        std::copy( data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>( std::cout," " ));
        }
        else
            std::cout << *iter;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char**argv )
{
    testParser<double>( qi::double_ );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As sehe does [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18391326/2417774), you can easily rename `qi::_r1` and `qi::_r2` to `min` and `max` respectively helping the readability of the rule by using: `qi::_r1_type min; qi::_r2_type max; mrule %= qi::eps[ min = std::numeric_limits<T>::max(), max = std::numeric_limits<T>::min() ] >> -( qi::omit[ qi::int_[ ph::reserve( qi::_val,qi::_1 ) ] ] >> *rule[ ph::if_(min>qi::_1)[ min=qi::_1 ], ph::if_(max<qi::_1)[ max=qi::_1 ] ] );`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I see the problem correctly, but even if that's a little different, you can store several values without hassle:

```
struct data {
  int _a;
  int _b;
  data(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {};
};
```

And construct it:

```
qi::eps[qi::_val = phx::construct<data>(1, 2)]
```

Comment: The problem I got stuck on was with qi::phrase_parse. If you check the three trivial test cases in my question ... I felt like semantic actions should have work! :-) But they did not. `cv_and_he` came with information that it was not supposed to work like I expected. He tried some `trick` but it was not general enough and this sequence of experiments already helped me to understand that it was dead end. I was able to find the solution using qi::grammar and inherited attributes that I can use for what I need in semantic rules.